# How can I force SDL_Init() to fail?

Tags: sdl

Is there a way to reliable force `SDL_Init()` to fail for use in a test case?

Comment: Do you mean for `SDL_Init()` to return -1?

Comment: Yes, for it to return non-zero and set the error to be retrieved with SDL_GetError

Comment: Why not just replace `SDL_Init();` with -1 and call `SDL_SetError()`? As far as i can see from source the only function of `SDL_GetError()` is to read text from error buffer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did during development. I was hoping to have my automatic test verify init errors are being handled.

Comment: I haven't had the seen SDL_Init() fail ever, does that even happen on modern systems?

Comment: I haven't been able to do it--so I don't know. Perhaps I shouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28177/discussion-between-armin-and-micah-carrick)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can force it fail by not including the SDL dynamically linked library (SDL.dll).