# How can I force glfwInit() to fail for debugging purposes?

Tags: debugging, error-handling, runtime-error, glfw

Similar to [How can I force SDL_Init() to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993646/how-can-i-force-sdl-init-to-fail), I'd like to force `glfwInit()` to fail to ensure that my error logging code is working properly. How might I do this? I'm on Linux, so Linux-compatible answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glfwInit()` may fail under a number of circumstances

- If no monitor is connected
- If you are using a GLFW library compiled for the wrong windowing system ([such as Wayland on X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431686/glfwinit-fails-what-should-i-do))
- Dynamic libraries that GLFW depend on [failed to be loaded](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/9a87635686c7fcb63ca63149c5b179b85a53a725/src/wl_init.c#L563)
- if On Wayland, the compositor does not provide the `xdg-shell` protocol (replaced `wl-shell`).
- etc

Your best bet is to look into the source code for GLFW. Try to see if you can find anything in [`_glfwInitX11`](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/9a87635686c7fcb63ca63149c5b179b85a53a725/src/x11_init.c#L1322) or [`_glfwInitWayland`](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/9a87635686c7fcb63ca63149c5b179b85a53a725/src/wl_init.c#L506) that you can make fail.

If none of this can be achieved, you could try compiling GLFW yourself, after having rewritten `glfwInit` to fail for every call.